# Responce time for steps (WebDriver + Jmeter)

Tags: selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I have a test, where I:

1. Go to the link
2. Input Login and Password and press Login button
3. Press Some link
4. Press LogOut button

I run it in JMeter with 5 users, and I should save some data in csv file, like:

UserName, Login (or smth from 4 steps about), Average time.

In output I should have a file where I can see, that 5 user do step "Login" for average time (5 second for example). How to know average time - find all steps "Login" plus all time and divide on user count (5)?

Answer (score 0):

Implement it in JMeter as follows:

- WebDriver Sampler with Label `Go to the link`
- WebDriver Sampler with label `Login`
- WebDriver Sampler with label `Navigate`
- WebDriver Sampler with label `Logout`

WebDriver code for each sampler should look as follows:

```
 WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
 // put code for login, navigate, logout, etc.
 WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

WebDriver session will remain between samplers and JMeter is smart enough to measure average response times, just add a relevant listener, i.e. [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report)

See [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) guide for more tips and tricks.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not passed for me, I use JUnit. Here's my code:

```
public class LoadTestTwo extends TestCase {
    private WebDriver driver;
    public FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    public int index=0;
    private long start;
    private long end;
    boolean alreadyExists = new File("C:\\output.csv").exists(); //write estimate time to file

    public LoadTestTwo(){
        reset();
          //start = System.currentTimeMillis();  
    }

      public void end(){
          end = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
      }

      public long duration(){
          return (end-start);

      }

      public void reset(){
          start = 0;
          end = 0;
      }

    public LoadTestTwo(String testName){
        super(testName);
    }


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();  
    }


    @Test
    public void testTestLoad() throws InterruptedException, IOException, FileNotFoundException {        
        LoadTestTwo t = new LoadTestTwo();
        try {
            CsvWriter csvOutput = new CsvWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\output.csv",true),',');  
            if (!alreadyExists) {  
                csvOutput.write("Users");  
                csvOutput.write("Steps");  
                csvOutput.write("Average Time");
                csvOutput.endRecord();  
            }  

                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                t.reset();
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                driver.get("somelink"); //just hided the real link
                t.end();
                csvOutput.write("LoadTest2");  
                csvOutput.write("Go to URL");  
                csvOutput.write("" + t.duration());  
                csvOutput.endRecord();  
                t.reset();
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm:authLogin")).sendKeys("User1");
                driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm:authPassword")).sendKeys("123456");
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm:btnLogin")).click();
                t.end();
                csvOutput.write("LoadTest2");  
                csvOutput.write("Login");  
                csvOutput.write("" + t.duration());  
                csvOutput.endRecord();  
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(4000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                t.reset();
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                driver.findElement(By.className("log")).click();
                t.end();
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                csvOutput.write("LoadTest2");  
                csvOutput.write("Go to Administration");  
                csvOutput.write("" + t.duration());  
                csvOutput.endRecord(); 
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(7000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                t.reset();
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='logout']")).click();
                t.end();
                csvOutput.write("LoadTest2");  
                csvOutput.write("Logout");  
                csvOutput.write("" + t.duration());  
                csvOutput.endRecord();  

                /*FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File("C:\\output.csv"));
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                String st;
                while ((st = br.readLine()) != null){
                    System.out.println(st);
                }*/

                csvOutput.close();


        } catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Here's just one user, I'll make 5 Jar files and start it in JMeter.